# What is "buid" for Spring Boot Multi-Module Maven projects?

Tags: java, maven, build, multi-module

I'm learning about Spring Boot multi module Maven projects and I'm using Eclipse and I try to understand what exactly means "build". In the past I worked with Maven and I made web app with Servlets, Spring MVC, etc and I just click "Run on server"... but now I need to click "Maven build", then I need to clean and install. Also Eclipse asks me for JDK now...

Why should I build first and what exactly is build in Maven? This build is only for multi-module projects? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you run the modules on your tomcat you can use (and just execute) [tomcat7:run-war](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/run-war-mojo.html) maven plugin with single goal:

```
tomcat7:run-war
```